# style inside dl selector enable to style the next selector

Tags: css, sass

i can style my dl element with the background, but not my form-row element. what i'm doing wrong ? i'm working on scss file

here the html :

```css
.zend_form {

   background : grey
}

.zend_form > .form-row {
    background: yellow
    border: 3px solid #D2CFC7;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 58px;
    padding-left: 85px;
    padding-right: 85px;
    padding-bottom: 76px;
    margin-bottom: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="form_signup">
    <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
    <dl class="zend_form">

     <div class="from-row">
       <div class="from-group form_ligne" id="form_ligne_login">
         <span id="login-label"><label for="login" class="form_label optional">Identifiant (adresse mail)</label></span>
         <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="" onpaste="return false">
       </div>
     </div>
 </dl>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: _“what i'm doing wrong ?”_ - for starters: You are presenting mere snippets that lack context, instead of a proper [mre].

Comment: just updated !!!

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com as you can see nothing append the the form-row

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com my fault zend didn't generate the decorator correctly many thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a typo in the name of the class. Replace `.from-row` with `form-row`.

```css
.zend_form > .form-row {
    border: 1px solid #D2CFC7;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 58px;
    padding-left: 85px;
    padding-right: 85px;
    padding-bottom: 76px;
    margin-bottom: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="form_signup">
    <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
    <dl class="zend_form">

     <div class="form-row">
       <div class="from-group form_ligne" id="form_ligne_login">
         <span id="login-label"><label for="login" class="form_label optional">Identifiant (adresse mail)</label></span>
         <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="" onpaste="return false">
       </div>
     </div>
 </dl>   
  </form>
</div>
```

By the way, later you are using `from-group`. Maybe you have a typo here too.

Comment: sorry yes it's scss syntax

Comment: just updated the problem @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com